# CSV To headers and Exploding results into custom class

Tags: python, loops, csv

```
class SalesRecord():
def __init__(self, *args):
    self.ProductID = args[0]
    self.Date = args[1]
    self.StoreNum = args[2]
    self.Units = args[3]
    self.PricePerUnit = args[4]
    self.Total = args[5]



salesreader = csv.reader(salesfile)
e1 = []
e2 = []
index = 0
for row in salesreader:
    if index != row:
        e2.append(SalesRecord(*row))
    else:
        e1.append(row)
```

I am trying to take the first row of the data set and assign the column headers as e1 and explode out the detail on e2. I am struggling with the iteration of a list position.

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `next()` function to read a single row from the CSV file. That way you do not need to add special logic inside the `for` loop to handle the first row. If you are using Python 3.x, you should open your CSV with the `newline=''` parameter.

```
import csv

class SalesRecord():
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.ProductID = args[0]
        self.Date = args[1]
        self.StoreNum = args[2]
        self.Units = args[3]
        self.PricePerUnit = args[4]
        self.Total = args[5]

    def __str__(self):
        # Text to display if SalesRecord is printed
        return "SalesRecord:\n  ProductID {}\n  Date {}\n  StoreNum {}\n  Units {}\n  PricePerUnit {}\n  Total {}".format(
            self.ProductID, self.Date, self.StoreNum, self.Units, self.PricePerUnit, self.Total)


with open('input.csv', newline='') as salesfile:
    salesreader = csv.reader(salesfile)

    # Construct a SalesRecord using the CSV header elements
    e1 = SalesRecord(*next(salesreader))       

    # Read the remaining rows into e2
    e2 = []

    for row in salesreader:
        e2.append(row)

print(e1)
print(e2)
```

So if you had an `input.csv` file that contained for example:

```
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6
1,2,3,4,5,6
a,b,c,d,e,f
```

This would print the following output:

```
SalesRecord:
  ProductID col1
  Date col2
  StoreNum col3
  Units col4
  PricePerUnit col5
  Total col6
[['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']]
```

Note: The `__str__()` function is a way of telling Python what to display if your class is printed.